# How should I proceed to get all files uncompressed? NTFS, Win8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, compression

I had a very small SSD for my Windows 8.1 Pro; that is the reason I activated [NTFS compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression).

I now have a large SSD and want to get rid of it for good.

Since I already have unticked on the system drive:

> Compress this drive to save disk space

And applied to all subdirectories, I am surprised to see some files were obviously not decompressed:

[image: some compressed files remained]

I tried to boot into safe mode minimal and do the decompression again. Little to no success, there are still compressed files.

Disclaimer: This question is not about the rationale on this topic. It's purely:

### How should I proceed to get all files uncompressed?

Comment: You have uncompress it using media of windows 8.1. In system Image Recovery Option.